# PHP Query - Help linking two querys into 1 echo statement

Tags: php, mysql, join

so i have blog posts echoed out in their own 'blogpost' div.

I then underneath that have another div which contains the posts comments.

I have a table called 'posts' and this contains everything to do with the post. I then have another called... 'comments' which contains information.

The way i wanted this to work is that there is a field in 'comments' called updatepostid. And this contains the id of the blogpost that it is associated with.

The issue comes when echoing them out. I can get the comments to echo out with something like:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments';
```

But as soon as i do e.g.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE updatepostid = "'.$postID.'"';
```

Nothing is shown. I beleive this is because the blogpost and comments are not in the same echo.

I am unsure of how to go about getting them into the same echo statement though.

So, here is what it looks like currently:

```
    <?php

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE buildID = '.$_GET['id'].' LIMIT '.$limit.''; 
     try 
{ 
     $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
     $stmt->execute(); 
} 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($rows as $row):

    $postID = $row['postID'];
    $text = $row['text'];
    $date = $row['date'];

echo basicbbcode ('

    <div class="blogtest">

    <form action="process/updatepost.php" class="updatepost" method="post">
        <input type="button" class='.$editenabled.' value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" class="saveupdatebutton" value="Save">
        <input type="hidden" class="postid" name="postid" value="'.$postID.'">

        <div class="text">

            <div class="buildtext">'.$text.'</div>

            <div class="editor"><textarea name="ckeditor"id="ckeditor" class="ckeditor">'.$text.'</textarea></div>

        </div>

    </form>

    </div>

    ')?>

    <?php

    // Get comments

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM comments'; 
     try 
        { 
     $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
     $stmt->execute(); 
        } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($rows as $row):

    $commentID = $row['commentID'];
    $usercommentID = $row['userID'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $updatepostid = $row['updatepostid'];

    ?>

    <div class="commentsbox">
        <div id="textcomment"><?php echo "$usercommentID: $comment";?></div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above is terrible i know... but its just to show you what im working with.

I was thinking about using an INNER JOIN query but still just cant get my head around it.

Any help on getting it into one echo statement?

Comment: `I beleive this is because the blogpost and comments are not in the same echo.` -- No. It's because your query doesn't do what you think it does. Try executing it directly, in your command line / terminal / phpMyAdmin and see if you get any output.

Comment: Agree with @AmalMurali - Feels more like your `updatepostid` column don't match the `$postID` variable.

Comment: try this before and comment out the `$smt` try `$echo $postID;` once verified, run a single instance of `$smt` test the result `print_r($rows);` if it then works, and you tried your sql in your database command box, then try the other one! there you would be up to the current momment, nothing will probably go wrong besides your future actions, dont pile problems over problems

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables should **never** go directly in your query. PDO supports data placeholders to add user data to your query, so be disciplined about using these. This is extremely dangerous code you have here.

Comment: Thanks for the information, somehow I must have miss entered some fake comments and given them the wrong postID. Once sorted out it works fine. Amazing how i overlooked it! As for the SQL injection,this site is hosted locally and once I get things working ill go and make t secure with help from a friend.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your first `$rows` variable (used with the posts query) when you fetch the comments. You'll need to use different variable names for those. To keep things easier to follow, try using descriptive names such as `foreach ($postRows as $postRow)` and `foreach ($commentRows as $commentRow)`